# How to return HTML on a function

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm trying to return some HTML in a function and I don't understand why it doesn't work, it seems easy but I can't find the solution.
It doesn't display anything, but when I return some console.log it works well.

Can someone help me, please?

Here's my code :

```
displayIcon(item) {
    if (item.SocialNetwork.name.toLowerCase() === "facebook") {
      console.log('fb')
      return (<i className={"fab fa-facebook-f"}></i>)
    } else if (item.SocialNetwork.name.toLowerCase() === "twitter") {
      console.log('tw')
      return (<i className={"fab twitter"}></i>)
    } else if (item.SocialNetwork.name.toLowerCase() === "pinterest") {
      console.log('pt')
      return (<i className={"fab pinterest"}></i>)
    } else if (item.SocialNetwork.name.toLowerCase() === "linkedin") {
      console.log('li')
      return (<i className={"fab linkedin"}></i>)
    } else if (item.SocialNetwork.name.toLowerCase() === "flickr") {
      console.log('fl')
      return (<i className={"fab flickr"}></i>)
    } else {
      console.log('Unknown social network')
      return (<div>Unknown social network</div>)
    }
  }

render() {
  return (<div>
    {
      this.props.social.map((item, i) => {
        this.displayIcon(item)
      })
    }
  </div>);
}
```

Comment: Remove the `{}` around `this.displayIcon()`. You're not returning anything from the map function.

Comment: Thanks @DragoşPaulMarinescu ! It works :-)))

Answer (score 1):

You do not return inside your map so you are just getting an array of undefined items.

```
this.props.social.map((item, i) => {
  return this.displayIcon(item)
})
```

or

```
this.props.social.map(item => this.displayIcon(item))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are running `this.displayIcon` inside your `.map` but aren't returning anything. Try this:

```
this.props.social.map((item, i) => this.displayIcon(item))
```